# WaitForMultipleObjects functionality in Boost

Tags: boost

I need the functionality of `WaitForMultipleObjects` in a multiplatform project.
What can I use from Boost to replace this ?

Comment: As far as I know, on other platforms like Linux, there is no direct equivalent to WaitForMultipleObjects from WinAPI

maybe you should have a look at boost::condition_variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer to this question: Doesn't exist.

However I have found and answer on http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2004/12/77175.php

Hope will help for the others

*Waiting for a condition and waiting for multiple objects are not as closely related at it might seem at first glance. 
A condition does not carry state, while the handle you are waiting for does. A condition simply signals that a state change has appeared. Specifically a state change of a ceratin (group of) variable(s) that is (are) protected by a mutex. 
What you rather would need to have, is that a certain condition be signalled when an operating system supplied handle changes state. I ended having created a small class 
"wfmo" with the condition to be signalled as a member. The class has meber functions to add 
operating system handles, and creates a thread internally that blocks on WaitForMultipleObjects. 
On return it signals the condition.*

*This is working. However I think it does address the problem only in a pragmatic way. (And I am afraid the runtime overhead due to the additional thread might be not negligible in some cases.) To do away with the additional thread you would need to modify the 
condition.wait() to accept the handles of the objects you are waiting for. Internally the wait currently uses WaitForSingleObject. 
It would be a simple task to replace them by WaitForMultipleObjects. 
But: You need to supply operating system handles then! And this breaks portability. 
The real problem is: Boost currently does not have a low level IO concept, that defines its 
own IO handles and the like. 
Although this topic has been repeadetly discussed on the list there still 
has been no proposal (at least formally) that addresses theses issues. Yes there have been proposals about networking and the like but not about general (low level) IO. (On top of which I think, networking should be built.)*

Comment: This is from 2004, boost::asio should now be the i/o-handle library.

Comment: @Christopher Boost::asio does not have WaitForMultipleObjects functionality. I need to port some Windows code to Linux and I don't want to re-write the logic.

Comment: No, it does not have direct support for WaitForMultipleObjects, but implements something equivalent through the use of select. I don't know what you are looking for, (because you didn't say) but the statement, that boost doesn't have a asynchronous I/O library is (more or less) wrong today.

Comment: I need to replace the the calls to `WaitForMultipleObjects` with something similar that works on Linux. Can you point to that part of the `asio` that is equivalent so i can start evaluating it ? Thanks

Comment: On what objects do you do your WaitForMultipleObjects?